# How to use mobile data instead on WiFi (while WiFi is on) on Android phone?

Tags: wi-fi, mobile-data, internet, proxy

I am looking to use an Android phone as the proxy server, so I set up "Proxy Server" on my Android phone -> Connected phone to Wifi -> Got local IP of phone -> Connecting to phone thru LAN (from my local computer) thru the proxy and it's working, but the phone is using same WiFi connection to connect back to the Internet.

So I got 2 questions:

1. Is there any way to force Android to use mobile data to access the internet while having the WiFi on?
2. I can not connect thru that proxy from the Internet when I am using my phone's IP address. I am getting the error "Connection refused", I did some research and looks like some ISP blocking some or most ports. How do I deal with/bypass that?

Comment: **(1)** Why don't you connect PC to phone through hotspot, and phone to internet through mobile data? You can go other way too; create hotspot on PC and connect phone to it through wi-fi, as well as to internet through mobile data. Its also possible to connect to a third wi-fi source while the phone is using mobile data for internet. All situation require some manual configurations on both sides, and necessarily a rooted phone. **(2)** You have to deal with Carrier Grade NAT. See this: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205807/218526

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect to a local network from a public network..

Using WiFi allows the local connection as you've mentioned but using Internet is different because it is not a device on the same WiFi network ( local )

To connect to a public ip, the device should have a server... Try looking into making a simple http server for either the PC or Phone.