# want to use my phone as a public proxy

Tags: hardware, proxy

I have a rooted Samsung Galaxy S5 running Android 6.0.1. I want to use the phones mobile data as a proxy for my VPS. Obviously they are not in the same network so the proxy needs to be public for my vps to access it. Another problem might be the ISP's, who block the ports. Can anybody help me out on how I do that :D

thanks in advance

Comment: Check your MNO contract if such a scenario is allowed at all. Anyway blocked ports are usually not a "problem" but a insurmountable obstacle.

Comment: Related: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205807/218526

Comment: @IrfanLatif I cant even manage to access the ssh server on my phone. I'm trying to access it form my pc connected to my home connection per cmd with the command: ssh IP -p 2222 it says either connection timed out or  network unreachable. The phone is connected to 4G Data. The IP shown on the ssh software - SSHDroid, SimpleSSHD etc. - differs from the public IP that I see when accessing sites like whatsmyip. So I guess Im sitting behind a CGNAT? How do I make the ssh server work and where can I run that command? ssh <phone_user>@<ip> -p 2222. Sorry for asking so many questions, newbie here :S

Comment: @MeyvisArtur I think all of your queries are addressed in above mentioned answer. See [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214811/218526) for a more detailed step by step guide. If you are not sure about a certain step, please edit your question to include that.