# How to connect two phones via SSH with a central SSH server?

Tags: ssh, remote-access

I have two phones `A` and `B` which use Mobile Data. I would like to connect from phone `A` to phone `B`, the latter has an SSH server running on port `8022`. The central SSH server is running on AWS and has an Elastic IP.
Phone `A` can connect to AWS Server directly at port `22`, so can phone `B`.

AWS Server configuration:

```
GatewayPorts yes
TCP forward yes
Password Authentication Yes
```

Further, I have forwarded port `9099` on the AWS SSH server to local port `8022` on phone `B`:

```
~$ ssh -NR 9099:localhost:8022 user@Remoteip
```

By running `netstat -tpln` on the AWS SSH server, I can see that `9099` is in listening mode.

But when I ssh from phone `A` into the AWS server at port `9099`, it says timed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I have understood from your question:

You have two phones `A` and `B`, which are connected to internet through Mobile Data. Phone `B` has a SSH server running, listening on port `8022`. You want to login from phone `A` to phone `B`, but since the later doesn't have a public IP, you want to create a reverse SSH tunnel from phone `B` to another SSH server running on AWS cloud, listening on port `22`. In this way you want that all traffic received on port `9099` on AWS SSH server should be forwarded to port `8022` on phone `B`, so that phone `A` can access it on internet.

If I understood correctly, the simplest thing you have to do is:

- On AWS run a SSH server, which is listening on port `22`. Since you are able to login to this server from both phones `A` and `B`, I think you have done it correctly. Let's say your login user here is `server_user` and IP address is `server_ip`.

  You need two additional keywords in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, should look like this exactly (no extra spaces):

  ```
  # /etc/ssh/sshd_config

  AllowTcpForwarding yes
  GatewayPorts yes
  ```

  After changing configuration, don't forget to restart server.

  - First parameter ensures that port forwarding is allowed i.e. you'll be able to create tunnel.
  - Second parameter ensures that the reverse tunnel will listen on all network interfaces, and not only the local (`loopback`) interface on AWS server.
- On phone `B` run a SSH server, which is listening on port `8022`, let's say your login userame is `phone_user` (Termux's SSHD requires no username).

  Do test if you can login to this server. For instance create hotspot on phone `A` or `B` or connect both to some third WiFi network. Now login from phone `A` to phone `B`. If it doesn't work, troubleshoot the problem, most likely with password / key authentication.
- On phone `B` create a reverse tunnel i.e. forward AWS SSH server's port `9099` to phone `B`'s (local) port `8022`:

  ```
  ~$ ssh -NR 9099:localhost:8022 server_user@server_ip
  ```

  This can be done on Termux or use some GUI app like `ConnectBot`.

  To test if the the tunnel works correctly, on AWS server:

  ```
  ~$ ssh phone_user@localhost -p 9099
  ```

  It should login you to phone `B`.
- On phone `A`, login to phone `B` through AWS SSH server:

  ```
  ~$ ssh phone_user@server_ip -p 9099
  ```

If it doesn't work, repeat the steps.

**RELATED:**

- [How to connect to Android through SSH over 3G/4G public IP?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205807/218526)
- [How to run SSH/SFTP server for multiple user logins with password authentication on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/209918/218526)

Comment: Id like to confirm that if i need to make http requests on Phone B via Phone A,do i need to have a server or a Client should get the job done

Comment: @EhtizadZashkiyor sorry couldn't understand what you mean by `http requests`. Do you want to host a web server on phone `B`?

Comment: Basically I would like to connect Phone A to Phone B and access the Internet through phone B .So do I need to have a server on Phone B to do this or a client on phone B can do the same ?

Comment: @EhtizadZashkiyor You can't connect a client to client. At least one end should be a server.

Comment: Ok.Let me configure the server and update about this .