# Are there any ports opened on an Android device by default?

Tags: system, default-applications

Title says it all.  Looking at a Samsung S10 phone and would like to know if there are any ports opened on device by default?

Comment: Setup adb and try this command: `adb shell netstat -natup`. To emulate factory default conditions, a factory reset is needed to go back to factory/pristine state. Safe mode might also work, but I never cross checked the two for opened ports, so can't say for sure.

Comment: Need clarification: is the question about a specific device (Samsung S10 with Google and Samsung services), or vanilla Android (AOSP)?

Comment: Open ports is a vague term. Do you mean listening ports or the ports which can be accessed externally? There can be some listening ports like `5555` used by ADBD and `5353` used by `mdnsd`. Both are used to discover devices on local network. But usually [phones aren't accessible from internet](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205807/218526), so open ports don't make sense. // @Firelord I think OP means listening ports. So `netstat -nltup` (or `ss -nltup`) gives more precise results. `-a` gives all results including the ports used for outgoing connections which aren't open ports technically.