# Connections towards specific inbound ports on cell phones

Tags: networking, mobile-network

Imagine a cell phone connected to internet via 3G/4G/5G, but not via wifi (and a router). Wifi is either temporarily disabled on the cell phone, or not available at that area.

**Can that cell phone run (for instance) an FTP server that listens on port 2121?** Is that something that usual telephony networks allow you to do, on your cell phone, or is that very rare?

I would like to access files on the cell phone with an FTP client located on any other device in the world. I know that, when the cell phone is not connected to a router via wifi, its IP is (usually) dynamic, and changes every time the phone/communication is restarted. Let's assume that that would not be a problem for me. I would just manually find out what is the IP dynamically assigned to the cell phone, and I would "type" that IP into the FTP client.

I have tried all that, with no luck. It looks like telephony networks don't allow TCP/IP connections "towards" specific inbound ports on a cell phone. Internet providers via fiber optic/ADSL/cable do allow those connections (I can, of course, set up an FTP server on my desktop PC behind a router), but it looks like telephony networks don't allow that. Is that right? If so, is there a solution to that? Are telephony networks that allow that common?

Comment: [How to connect to Android through SSH over 3G/4G public IP?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205807/218526)